# Azure AD Authorize Error of AuthenticationFailed: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid'

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I have 2 projects, one is for API and 2nd is for to view and get data by using 1st project's APIs. For both I have implemented Azure AD authentication but my issue is when try to call API from 2nd project back-end(C#) with Bearer token but in response i am getting below error.

> Note: I have use [Authorize] Filter in each and every class and the method in both project.

Error

> AuthenticationFailed: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match 'kid': 'SSQdhI1cKvhQEDSJxE2gGYs40Q0', 
>   token: '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT","kid":"SSQdhI1cKvhQEDSJxE2gGYs40Q0"}.{"aud":"1e615ddb-ad4d-4e65-98de-c6f5db1ae08a","iss":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/5c58f0d9-2f98-4eb0-91f2-ec6afd4242f8/v2.0","iat":1518520450,"nbf":1518520450,"exp":1518524350,"aio":"Y2NgYHiknfZAIvPElucJpgeZzRa5AAA=","azp":"1e615ddb-ad4d-4e65-98de-c6f5db1ae08a","azpacr":"1","e_exp":262800,"oid":"159f0ec6-c5b9-4bfc-88d0-77924bd40b3f","sub":"159f0ec6-c5b9-4bfc-88d0-77924bd40b3f","tid":"5c58f0d9-2f98-4eb0-91f2-ec6afd4242f8","uti":"t8CU6YtsHE-5M9TbQm4aAA","ver":"2.0"}'.

Start class ConfigureServices Method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdB2C(options =>  Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))           
        .AddCookie();

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
        });
    }
```

Start class Configure method

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Class for to get Bearer Token

```
public class ServicePrincipal
{        
    static string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/{Policy}/v2.0/";  
    static string clientId = "XXX"; 
    static string clientSecret = "XXX"; 
    static string resource = "XXX"; 

    static public async Task<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSAAsync()
    {
        return await GetS2SAccessToken(authority, resource, clientId, clientSecret);
    }

    static async Task<Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult> GetS2SAccessToken(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var clientCredential = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,clientCredential);  
        return authenticationResult;
    }
}
```

Controller method from where I am trying to calling 1st project's API

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerGroupAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            var token = await ServicePrincipal.GetS2SAccessTokenForProdMSAAsync();                
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.AccessToken);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.GetAsync("http://localhost:49942/api/customermodule/v0.3/customergroup");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string receiveStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Error = e.Message });
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything or am i doing wrong?, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your `GetCustomerGroupAsync` action, you are using the client credentials flow in your website backend to access the secured resource (Web API) with Azure AD B2C. As [Azure Active Directory B2C: Types of applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-apps#current-limitations) mentions under the Current limitations section as follows:

> **Daemons/server-side apps**
>
> Apps that contain long-running processes or that operate without the presence of a user also need a way to access secured resources such as web APIs. These apps can authenticate and get tokens by using the app's identity (rather than a user's delegated identity) and by using the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow.
>
> **This flow is not currently supported by Azure AD B2C. These apps can get tokens only after an interactive user flow has occurred.**

Moreover, you could follow the git samples below to implement your requirement:

[An ASP.NET Core 2.0 web API with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapi)

[An ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp)

Comment: I got it, this is the perfect sample project without any error https://github.com/dzimchuk/azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to retrive access token, it must be a call to OAuth endpoint. Try with the below one to get Azure AD access token

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/token
```

More over, just need to make sure the authorization header is constructed in valid format: Bearer

Comment: @DarshanDave could you enable debug mode and give some hints? Note that all parameters must be valid.

Comment: please check screen shot 1) http://prntscr.com/ieg6ce 2) http://prntscr.com/ieg5yk 3) http://prntscr.com/ieg6ou

Comment: I think there is something wrong here. The client ID is actually the application ID of the application you registeed in Azure AD. Resource is not the same client ID. It is `https://management.azure.com` ifwhich is the resource management endpoint to call One of the interesting things here is if you pass invalid parameters, you still get the access token but it is not the valid one.